# Change CLASS for FIRST child with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, css-selectors, attr

There is bootstrap carousel slider and I wanna assign first #slide-item class = active to start carousel work, cause this doesn't get it

```
function previewImages() {

var $preview = $('#preview').empty();
if (this.files) $.each(this.files, readAndPreview);

function readAndPreview(i, file) {

    if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i.test(file.name)) {
        return alert(file.name + " is not an image");
    } // else...

    var reader = new FileReader();

    $(reader).on("load", function () {
        $preview.prepend('<div class="carousel-item" id="slide-item"><img class="d-block photo-preview" src="' + this.result + '"/></div>');
    });
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

}

$("#preview #slide-item:first-child").attr('id', 'carousel-item active');
```

}

please help :)

Comment: First guess would be to change the last line to: `$("#preview #slide-item:first-child").addClass('carousel-item active');`

Comment: nope. don't work

Comment: Looks like you need to do more than just assign the class to `active`.  Or your selector is wrong.  Either way assigning the classname to the `id` attribute certainly isn't the way to go.

Comment: Perhaps you can create two [mcve]s - one that shows a "carousel" working and one that shows how you want it to work using this code.  It's unlikely to be just a case of adding a class if it's a bootstrap component.